# Auto login in twitter account using username and password

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using `Twitter` `oauth` for achieving the auto-login concept by providing the username and password. I am only able to get the data from my Twitter account. How do i login to Twitter by providing the username and password as parameters to some function which may be Twitter API login function or whatever the function. Did anyone come across this issue? If so please process me the code or links.

I want to achieve the following using `oauth Twitter API` or `xauth`... or some script:

1. I have an icon (Twitter) in my air application which has some background details like url (www.twiiter.com), username, password.
2. If i click the Twitter icon, i want the Twitter site to login automatically and to be rendered on my AIR browser (webkit).
3. It can be anything like Twitter API or some script which does the login mechanism.

I am stuck with this, How do i login to Twitter using auto login?

Comment: Try tagging with air.

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter API no longer supports authenticating to Twitter with a user name and a password.  In order to use the API, you need to implement OAuth either by writing your own implementation (which I strongly advise again) or by using a library that someone else has written.

Which one you use depends largely on your development platform.